# Vlookup in VBA to work on Numbers in different format

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to make Vlookup in VBA work when 1 value is a Number and the other is a Number as Text format? I do not want to convert the format of any number.

The problem is I sometimes have reports from SAP and there the text formatted numbers are given. But i need to apply Vlookup in VBA and match in my table where numbers are number formatted. I can't convert all numbers to a number format as it takes time and I don't want to slow my macro.

Comment: If you are using VBA please supply sample code, and explain where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with an array formula.

I assume the table from A2 to B100 and the number to match at A1

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,IFERROR(A2:B100*1,A2:B100),2)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

If you are working with bigger ranges, it will be better to change to `INDEX` and `MATCH` like:

```
=INDEX(B2:B100,MATCH(A1,IFERROR(A2:A100*1,A2:A100),0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

However: if the ranges are very big, or by using whole columns, you will slow down excel a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>Is there any way to make Vlookup in VBA work when 1 value is a Number and the other is a Number as Text format?</sub>

An INDEX/MATCH function pair is likely the most effective method of lookup. Using IFERROR to pass the processing to an alternate MATCH seems viable.

```
'if the lookup 'numbers' are predominantly numeric
=index(sheet2!a:a, iferror(match(a2, sheet2!b:b, 0), match(text(a2, "0"), sheet2!b:b, 0))
'if the lookup 'numbers' are predominantly textual
=index(sheet2!a:a, iferror(match(text(a2, "0"), sheet2!b:b, 0), match(a2, sheet2!b:b, 0))
```

> <sub>I can't convert all numbers to a number format as it takes time and I don't want to slow my macro.</sub>

A Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish converts full columns of text-that-look-like-numbers to true numbers very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to use only VBA to make it work. SO text to column should also be in VBA code.

Comment: So use [TextToColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) in VBA then (sheeesh!).

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no sample data or code. Please supply sample setups in future.

I post this answer as a possible simpler answer than the other two IF the text formatted numbers are the one that you are supplying as the lookup value to the Vlookup function.

Worksheet Function:
`=VLOOKUP(VALUE(A1), LookupArray, 2, FALSE)`

You mention in 'Vlookup in VBA' and macros, so VBA code:

`retVal = Application.VLookup(CLng(lookupVal), LookupRange, 2, False)`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and below helped (I had SAP IDs in column 'B', replace the cell values and last row within range), this converts the SAP ID/number from General/Text/green arrowed format to numbers/values, which then can be looked up with numbers

`LR1 = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("B3:B" & LR1)
.Value = Evaluate(.Address & "*1")
End With`

Let me know if it helped!!!